# problems in building the oprenrisc toolchain

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, toolchain, binutils, vmware-workstation

I want to build the openrisc toochain on my virtual machine ubuntu 12.04. I succeed to do this one time before my vm crashed for some reasons, but now I am unable to do it.
I am following these instructions to achieve this http://openrisc.net/toolchain-build.html , in the mean time I can't build it the easy way or the by hand. I receive this message at the end of making the binutils (by hand) but I receive the same message from the easy too.

```
make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/binutils-build/bfd/po'
make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/binutils-build/bfd/po'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `info'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/binutils-build/bfd/po'
make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/binutils-build/bfd'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `info-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/binutils-build/bfd'
make[2]: *** [info-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/binutils-build/bfd'
make[1]: *** [all-bfd] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/binutils-build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution to this problem, I achieved this by installing these dependencies from the opencores page

```
    sudo apt-get -y install build-essential make gcc g++ flex bison patch \
texinfo libncurses5-dev libmpfr-dev libgmp3-dev libmpc-dev libzip-dev \
python-dev libexpat1-dev
```

Comment: Could you share how you find out what packages are missed?

Comment: Yes, I found that the toolchain used in this tutorial is out of date so I went to the opencores.org website and learn their manual or tutorial about the toolchain. And here it is the toolchain is working well, they will provide you with all the necessities to achieve your work. Also you will find that the tutorial mentioned in my question is incomplete. So this is the link if this interests you  http://opencores.org/or1k/OpenRISC_GNU_tool_chain